# find a gap in a given date range/year with multiple or single date ranges in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands, oracle19c

I have such a table with date ranges, There could be 1 or multiple date ranges, overlapping or consecutive as well.
I want to find out if there is a gap and if then show the missing date range for a part. the gap should be tested for the year 2024

```
part    start   end
a   1.1.2023    31.3.2024
a   1.1.2023    31.12.2025
a   1.7.2024    31.12.2025
b   1.1.2024    30.6.2024
b   1.7.2024    31.12.2024
c   1.10.2023   30.9.2024
d   1.1.2023    30.6.2024
d   1.12.2024   31.12.2025
```

so for part A there is no gap, 2 ranges are not consecutive but one of them cover the whole year 2024, so the part a should be filtered out.
part B has 2 ranges and they together cover the year 2024, thus filtered out.
part C has 1 date range till 30.9.2024 , so new date range will be start = 1.10.2024 and end = 31.12.2024.
part D has 2 date ranges and there is a gap in 2024,this new date range will be start=1.7.2024 and end 30.11.2024.

desired output

```
part    start       end
c       1.10.2024   31.12.2024
d       1.7.2024    31.12.2024
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT` the start- and end-dates to a single column and then use analytic functions to generate a cumulative count the number of starts minus ends to find when the ranges start and end and then `UNPIVOT` again to find the pairs (so if there is a gap in the range before and a gap in the range after then a single row is converted to two rows for both parts of the missing range) and then filter:

```sql
SELECT part,
       COALESCE(start_dt, DATE '2024-01-01') AS start_dt,
       end_dt - 1 AS end_dt
FROM   (
  SELECT part,
         LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY dt)
           AS prev_dt,
         dt,
         LEAD(dt, 1, DATE '2025-01-01') OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY dt)
           AS next_dt,
         SUM(type) OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY dt) AS in_range
  FROM   (
    SELECT part, dt, SUM(type) AS type
    FROM   (
      SELECT part, start_date, end_date + 1 AS end_date
      FROM   table_name
    )
    UNPIVOT (dt FOR type IN (start_date AS 1, end_date AS -1))
    GROUP BY part, dt
  )
)
UNPIVOT (
  (start_dt, end_dt) FOR range_type IN (
    (prev_dt, dt) AS 'before',
    (dt, next_dt) AS 'after'
  )
)
WHERE  (   start_dt IS NULL
       AND DATE '2024-01-01' < end_dt
       AND in_range > 0
       AND range_type = 'before'
       )
OR     (   start_dt < DATE '2025-01-01'
       AND in_range = 0
       AND range_type = 'after'
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (part, start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT 'a', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2024-03-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2025-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2024-07-01', DATE '2025-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2024-01-01', DATE '2024-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2024-07-01', DATE '2024-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', DATE '2023-10-01', DATE '2024-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2024-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', DATE '2024-12-01', DATE '2025-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'e', DATE '2024-07-01', DATE '2025-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'f', DATE '2024-04-01', DATE '2024-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'g', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'h', DATE '2025-01-01', DATE '2025-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PART | START_DT | END_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c | 2024-10-01 00:00:00 | 2024-12-31 00:00:00 |
| d | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 | 2024-11-30 00:00:00 |
| e | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 |
| f | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-03-31 00:00:00 |
| f | 2024-10-01 00:00:00 | 2024-12-31 00:00:00 |
| g | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-12-31 00:00:00 |
| h | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-12-31 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2B_UsKjx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date ranges are always within the month boundaries.

You can do it by joining your table with a calendar dataset created by `CONNECT BY LEVEL`, then perform some additional joins :

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS ('1.1.2024', LEVEL - 1) as month_
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
),
cte1 AS ( -- filter out any part having no gaps
  SELECT part
  FROM mytable t
  LEFT JOIN cte c ON c.month_ BETWEEN t.start_ AND t.end_
  GROUP BY part
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT month_) < 12
),
cte2 AS ( -- this is to get parts that have gaps
  SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.part) AS cnt
  FROM cte1 p
  INNER JOIN mytable t ON t.part = p.part
),
cte3 AS ( -- This is to get missing months from each range
  SELECT part, start_, end_, month_, CNT
  FROM cte2 t
  INNER JOIN cte c ON c.month_ NOT BETWEEN t.start_ AND t.end_                  
),
cte4 AS ( -- For each part, the missing months must appear times the number of records retrieved (exemple c has 1, d has 2).
  SELECT part, month_
  FROM cte3
  GROUP BY part, month_, CNT
  HAVING COUNT(month_) = CNT
),
cte5 AS (
  SELECT part, month_, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY month_) rn,
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(month_, LAG(month_, 1, month_) OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY month_)) date_diff
  FROM cte4
  ORDER BY part, month_
),
cte6 AS (
  SELECT part, month_, rn - SUM(date_diff) OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY month_) AS grp
  FROM cte5
)
SELECT part, MIN(month_) AS start_date, LAST_DAY(MAX(month_)) AS end_date
FROM cte6
GROUP BY part, grp
```

Results :

```
PART    START_DATE  END_DATE
c       01.10.2024  31.12.2024
d       01.07.2024  30.11.2024
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EaibzqK4)

Comment: This does not always give the correct answer - Compare the output for your answer with these additional test cases [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UDsKTAa_) to the other answers.

Comment: Also, you appear to assume that the OP will always have date ranges that conform to the month boundaries; while the OP's data may conform to that they do not state that that is always true in the question so it is an additional assumption that you have made about the question.

Comment: Thanks @MT0 for the remarks, I have fixed it, here is a fiddle with your test cases https://dbfiddle.uk/0hmoWLmE

Comment: Added another test case for you, it should generate 3 ranges (before, between and after) that do not conform to the month boundaries; your code fails as it only outputs two rows for that brand (instead of three) and gets the wrong start and end dates. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oN068CeY)

Comment: Yes it fails, I have mentioned that my solution expect ranges with month boundaries only